# Atom Editor: How to configure keybindings with "^" key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

**What is the keymap configuration to toggle "Tree View: Reveal active file" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> in linux (german keyboard)?**

On Windows (english but german keyboard), the command "Reveal in Tree View" is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> per default.

I want the same keybinding on my linux system (german system, german keyboard). Per default it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> - which is a ridiculous combination, considering <kbd>\</kbd> is only possible with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. However, I am not able to figure out how to configure this in my keymap file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research and found that keybindings involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on linux switch to US layout. <kbd>^</kbd> is <kbd>`</kbd> on US keyboards, so the following works:

```
'.platform-win32, .platform-linux':
  'ctrl-shift-`': 'tree-view:reveal-active-file'
```

See [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13170) for more information on this.